# Condition in an inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I have an inequality that is reduced to :

$h(1 - 2v) \geq \frac{1-2v}{2}$

I need to find that :

- if $v < 1/2$, then $h \geq 1/2 $
- if $v > 1/2$, then $h \leq 1/2 $

But I am only able to find that  :

$h(1 - 2v) \geq \frac{1-2v}{2}$

$h \geq \frac{1-2v}{(1 - 2v) 2}$

$h \geq \frac{1}{2}$

It may be very simple for someone who is used with mathematics, but I don't see how to solve it. Could you please help me to find these conditions ?

Comment: You cannot multiply or divide an inequality by a negative number. For example $1 \leq 2$ but $(-1)(1) > (-1) (2)$.

Comment: Thank you, I see now my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You begin with an inequality
\begin{align}
h\cdot(1-2v) \geq \frac{1-2v}{2}.
\end{align}
Now the change in sign that you are trying to measure comes from when you divide across the inequality by (1-2v). Notice that if $v > \frac{1}{2}$, then $ 1 - 2v < 0$, i.e. is negative: so denoting by $|1-2v|$ the positive part of $1-2v$
\begin{align}
h\cdot(1-2v) \geq \frac{1-2v}{2} \iff -h\cdot |1-2v| \geq -\frac{|1-2v|}{2}.
\end{align}
Rearranging the inequality on the right hand side then gives us
\begin{align}
h\cdot(1-2v) \geq \frac{1-2v}{2} \iff h\cdot |1-2v| \leq \frac{|1-2v|}{2},
\end{align}
after which we can divide across by the positive $|1-2v|$ to obtain that $h \leq \frac{1}{2}$.

Now if instead $v < \frac{1}{2}$, we find that $1 - 2v > 0$ and so we can perform the division straight away to obtain that $h \geq \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There was an extra "+" at the beginning, sorry about that. Anyway, the last point of your answer is extacly where I was wrong, and it needed to be solved depending on if (1-2v) is positive or negative.

Comment: I see, not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

As noticed in the comments, there is a issue with your first step.

We should proceed as follows

$$h (1 - 2v) \geq \frac{1-2v}{2}$$

$$h (1 - 2v) - \frac{1-2v}{2} \ge 0$$

$$(1 - 2v) \left(h-\frac12\right) \ge 0$$

that is

- $1 - 2v\ge 0 \iff h-\frac12\ge 0$
- $1 - 2v \le 0\iff h-\frac12\le 0$

Comment: There was an extra "+" , sorry about this. Thank you for your answer. With the comment of @Kavi Rama Murthy, I see where my error is. I need to find first the threshold when (1- 2v) is positive/negative and then solve the inequality considering this. This was the point I missed.

Comment: @Marc Ah ok, I fix that! Indeed there was something strange with your solution.